# Flutter > Provider > Firebase | can't stream one object but another is streaming well and both of them really similar

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I'm working with flutter and provider and firbase.
when stream list of products it is streaming well.
but when want to stream orders return no thing.
Please help me

Here is product and order class

```
class Order {
  final String id;
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String status;
  final int total;

  Order({
    this.id,
    this.uid,
    this.email,
    this.status,
    this.total,
  });

  Order.fromFire(DocumentSnapshot doc)
      : id = doc.documentID,
        uid = doc['uid'],
        email = doc['email'],
        status = doc['status'],
        total = doc['total'];
}


import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Product {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final int price;

  Product({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
  });

  Product.fromFire(DocumentSnapshot doc)
      : id = doc.documentID,
        name = doc['name'],
        price = doc['price'];
}
```

And here the Streams

```
  Stream<List<Product>> getProductList() {
    return products.snapshots().map((snapShot) => snapShot.documents
        .map(
          (document) => Product.fromFire(document),
        )
        .toList());
  }

  Stream<List<Order>> getOrderList() {
    return orders.snapshots().map((snapShot) => snapShot.documents
        .map(
          (document) => Order.fromFire(document),
        )
        .toList());
  }
```

And here the providers

```
FirebaseService _db = FirebaseService();

        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => _db.getProductList(),
          catchError: (_, __) => null,
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) => _db.getOrderList(),
          catchError: (_, __) => null,
        ),
```

and reading the stream with

```
    List<Order> orderList = Provider.of<List<Order>>(context) ?? [];
    List<Product> productList = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context) ?? [];
```

But the product length is 5 and order length is 0 and have some orders in firestore

```
I/flutter (15121): product length 5
I/flutter (15121): order length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake that in Order model I defined int for order total price and when placing an order in services, total was double !:)

```
class Order {
  final String id;
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String status;
  final int total;
...

  placeOrder(
    FirebaseUser user,
    Address address,
    List<Product> products,
  ) async {
    String orderid = user.email + ' ' + DateTime.now().toString();
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      total = products[i].price + total;
    }
...
```